# How to specify a typescript version with atom

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I'm trying to figure out how to use a specific typescript version with atom. I have an older project which uses Backbone and does not compile with the latest version of typescript, and therefore requires an earlier version.

The closest answer I've found is this answer in the FAQ:

> Can I use a custom TypeScript compiler?
>   If it conforms the latest TypeScript services API then yes! Just set the path to typescriptServices.js in the package options.
>   https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/faq.md

I don't see how to make that work. The only typescriptServices.js file I find is part of Visual Studio 2015, which doesn't seem like it should impact atom or the atom-typescript package.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript
```

How can I force Atom to compile with a custom path to tsc.exe (or at least get it to use a specific version)?

**Edit**

I found the setting this talks about, but when installing typescript 1.0, there is no typescriptServices.js file. There is a tsc.js file, but if I update the setting to that, I get an error. It looks like this may not be possible, at least for a version as old as 1.0.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found the setting this talks about, but when installing typescript 1.0, there is no typescriptServices.js file. There is a tsc.js file, but if I update the setting to that, I get an error. It looks like this may not be possible, at least for a version as old as 1.0.

Yes. Its not possible as that version is not even API compatible with the latest TypeScript version.

Comment: I guess that is my answer, thanks. Wish TypeScript were easier to install standalone versions of to work with on the command line.

Comment: i.e. you use a particular version of alm.tools and its ts+ide for that version

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of atom-typescript (writing this November 2018) it simply uses the version in the node_modules directory of the project.

[From the atom-typescript faq](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/faq.md#which-version-of-typescript-does-atom-typescript-use)

> Which version of TypeScript does atom-typescript use?
>   Your current version installed in your node_modules. This gets determined once per open file so you might want to re-open your panes, if you've updated TypeScript in your project.

Comment: "Window: Reload" FTW! Thanks for the link-